# For a Viewbased project, how to add a "new view" to an "existing view" so that the new view should open left to right

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
    -(IBAction)loginButton:(id)sender;{
LoginViewController *login= [[LoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:back animated:YES];// I need a change here like below
//[self.navigationController pushViewController:login animated:YES];
}
```

I am trying to open a new view with a button action, and using above code the new view opens bottom to up. I want it to open left to right.

Answer (score 1):

you can set the [`modalTransitionStyle`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/modalTransitionStyle) property of the viewController.

But none of the allowed transistions (`UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical`, `UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal`, `UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve`, `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl`) equals the animation you get when pushing onto a navigation stack.

And this is by design. With the built-in animations a user can distinguish between a modal view and a pushed view.
By convention you can navigate back and forward from a pushed view a couple of times without changing the content. A modal view however is meant to interrupt the user in what he is currently doing do draw attention on something else, for example because he has to fill out a login sheet.

Pushed viewControllers and modal viewControllers are not just different ways for the developer to display something on the screen. You can't swap them arbitrarily. They have different semantics. It doesn't make sense that a modal viewController pretends to be a pushed viewController. And you shouldn't try to do something like this.

If you really want a navigation stack you can wrap your current viewController in a navigation controller and just hide the navigation bar.

Comment: Stick to the platform conventions! You will only confuse users and yourself by creating a modal dialog that masquerades as something else. This is the right answer!

Answer (score -1):

Try following code :

```
LoginViewController *login= [[LoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nav = [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:login]; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nav animated:YES];
```

You have to add your UIViewController into UINavigationController and then you can push it. So It will give effect of left to right, which is your requirement.

Comment: pushing a navigation controller onto another nav controller stack will lead to an exception. this is not allowed.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch : okey...I thought LoginViewController is already inside the UINavigationController.